# How to restrict deletion of opportunitycontactrole under opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger

I have to restrict deleting of opportunitycontactroles which are under an opportunity.Does anyone help me on this

Comment: Are there any certain condition that needs to be met before restricting delete ?

Comment: no conditions are there just to restrict from deleting

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't run triggers on OCR, detecting the delete event is impossible if using the standard layouts

If Classic, you could:

a) Override the View button with a VF page that was simply an `apex:detail`

b) Use jQuery in your VF page to css hide the Delete action on the OCR related list